# CORS(Cross-origin resource sharing) security risks

Tags: javascript, java, web

I'm using Spring boot to building an App with REST API.

The front-end user interfere build with pure browser side tech-stack and deploy on another server. This raises a CORS issue. Here are my two solutions:

1. Use Nginx as proxy server for both front-end and back-end.
2. Just enable CORS for API server.

Are there any security risks from enabling CORS? What is the best way of handling CORS issues?

Comment: Have you checked this out?
https://code.google.com/archive/p/html5security/wikis/CrossOriginRequestSecurity.wiki

Comment: what do you mean by "It case CORS issue"?

Comment: @user7294900 sorry, Type error. I mean "It cause CORS issue"